# Computer starts glitching and freezes

Tags: hardware

My computer is glitching and freezing after I use it for a bit. Have checked swap and computer maxes out at 4gb of ram which I have installed already. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Four gigabytes of RAM seems low these days if you're using a desktop environment, even on Linux, so a RAM upgrade may be a good value, cost effective, improvement.  Did you mean that all 4GB of RAM gets used, as does your swap?

Are you able to see *what* is using all of your RAM?  Google Chrome is known to use gigs of RAM, particularly if you have many tabs open.  Could you share a few more details about the applications you're running when you have the problem?